# Core 3.1 Console Application Bugsnag not working

Tags: c#, console-application, asp.net-core-3.1, bugsnag

Trying to get bugsnag working in a C# Asp.Net core 3.1 console application.
We have added Bugsnag.AspNet.Core version 2.2.1 to the application.
We have added Microsoft.Extensions.DependancyInjection version 3.1.15 to the application.

We made a simpler console application to get it down to just the basic application trying to use bugsnag.
Here is our code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.AddBugsnag(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.ApiKey = "";
            configuration.ReleaseStage = "Development";
        });

        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        serviceProvider.GetService<DurationService>().SetCallSummary();
    }
}
```

And the service.

```
public interface IDurationService
{
    void SetCallSummary();
}

public class DurationService : IDurationService
{
    private readonly Bugsnag.IClient _bugsnag;

    public DurationService(Bugsnag.IClient client)
    {
        _bugsnag = client;
    }

    public void SetCallSummary()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        } catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            _bugsnag.Notify(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

It keeps failing to initialize saying that there is a null object reference when hitting the service.
The null reference is to the bugsnag object that is being injected.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Bugsnag's ASP.NET Core library supports both AP.NET Core 1.x and 2.x, running on either .NET Core (1.0+) or the full .Net framework (4.6+). It looks like you are using version 3.1, which isn't yet supported.